# Selenium python is opening a different version of chrome than the one which I use for clearing data

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as UC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

# Start Chrome browser
CHROMEDRIVER = UC.Chrome() 


def start_driver():
    driver = UC.Chrome()
    delete_cache(driver)
    return driver


def delete_cache(driver):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('')")  # Create a separate tab than the main one
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])  # Switch window to the second tab
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')  # Open your chrome settings.
    perform_actions(driver, Keys.TAB + Keys.ENTER)  # Tab to the time select and key down to say "All Time" then go to the Confirm button and press Enter
    
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.close()  # Close that window
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  # Switch Selenium controls to the original tab to continue normal functionality.


def perform_actions(driver, keys):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys(keys)
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Performing Actions!')
    actions.perform()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = start_driver()
```

I'm trying to remove history of chrome using selenium automation, but the instance selenium opens is different from mine. Whenever I opened the browser and check the history is remaining but the selenium's version of chrome is different and it always has no history. i wanted to delete history from my chrome browser. I have checked my local instance by visiting sites and I see that the sites are getting cached. The instance opened by selenium doesn't cache though.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the automation is running in a separate instance of Chrome controlled by Selenium and doesn't affect your main Chrome browser.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the main instance to be effected not the instance controlled by selenium

Comment: @vamsishankar You can't do that with selenium. It's made for automation not interacting with system instances.